# CompressedInt Write?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

```
public static function Read(param1:IDataInput) : int
      {
         var _loc2_:* = 0;
         var _loc3_:int = param1.readUnsignedByte();
         var _loc4_:* = (_loc3_ & 64) != 0;
         var _loc5_:int = 6;
         _loc2_ = _loc3_ & 63;
         while(_loc3_ & 128)
         {
            _loc3_ = param1.readUnsignedByte();
            _loc2_ = _loc2_ | (_loc3_ & 127) << _loc5_;
            _loc5_ = _loc5_ + 7;
         }
         if(_loc4_)
         {
            _loc2_ = int(-_loc2_);
         }
         return _loc2_;
      }
```

someone can help me with write thing?
about to use in as3 server based but got only read thing

Comment: The piece of script you provided is a decompiled code. Without any comments or knowledge what kind of algorithm this thing implements, there's literally no telling what it does, even less how to compose a reverted algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As @Organis correctly said *"there's no telling how to compose a reverted algorithm."*

The only obvious things are listed below, so you'll have to do a lot of testing to get it right (that's how reverse engineering works, and it might take days or weeks). Good luck.

**Assessment**:

**(1)**

```
public static function Read(param1:IDataInput) : int
```

Look like it expects a (byte) array with two entries. I suspect you should write a Short (in hex formnat) but it'll be easier to just write two separate decimal values (since a `Short` is a value that spreads over two bytes).

```
public static function Write(val1 :int, val2 :int, targetBA :ByteArray) : void
{
    targetBA.length = 2;
    targetBA.position = 0;
    targetBA.writeByte( val1 );
    targetBA.writeByte( val2 );
    
    //# target ByteArray can now be "Read" by the other function as "param1"

}
```

As for the `Read` side...

Since the function returns a value to update some var, you should use as:

```
myResult = Read( targetBA );
```

Where `myResult` gets the function's returned `_loc2_` result.

**(2)**

```
var _loc4_:* = ( (_loc3_ & 64) != 0 );
```

This will give either a `0` or `64`. Is `0` if lower than 64, or else is `64` if equal or higher.
This is likely a quick shortcut to setting a `Boolean` like:

```
var _loc4_ :Boolean;
if (_loc3_ >= 64) { _loc4_ = true}
else { _loc4_ = false; }
```

**(3)**

```
_loc2_ = _loc3_ & 63;
```

Where `_loc2_` is set as an integer of either `0` or `63`.

**(4)**

```
while(_loc3_ & 128)
```

I don't know what this is trying to achieve. `(_loc3_ & 128)` is either `0` or `128`.
This `While(0)` or `While(128)` loop will run forever and there isn't any stopping `break;` at the end.

**(5)**

```
_loc2_ = _loc2_ | (_loc3_ & 127) << _loc5_;
```

This updates `_loc2_` with two values. The current *loc2* value is combined with a modified *loc3* value.

**(6)**

```
if(_loc4_)
```

Likely means `if( _loc4_ == true )`...